# Using optoisolator and triac with mcu to switch light on/off--need low power alternative

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator, triac

I'm using the schematic below to control a lamp (light bulb) with a microcontroller and I'm running the mcu (and moc3010) off of AA batteries. I just realized the moc3010 has an LED in it that needs typically 15ma. I'm assuming this 15ma needs to be applied constantly if I want the lamp to be on for say 6 hours a day--this will drain the batteries very quickly.

I need a lower power alternative (in 10s of uA to be constantly drawn instead of 15ma) for this to work, is that possible? Or am I better off just splitting the lamp wires and tying the first two to an ac adapter for the mcu/moc3010 and the second two to the light bulb-triac part?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Have you considered a latching relay? It will take more current than the optocoupler while switching, but no current at all until you need to switch back.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Ah, I was looking into relays but I didn't realize a latching one wouldn't need a constant current draw. Do you have any recommendations for a model that can handle a 100W lightbulb, 120VAC outlet

Comment: Since you have AC available, it seems silly to me to use batteries to power the controller - use an AC adaptor.

Comment: @user2665581 See [this relay](http://www.omron-ap.com/product_info/MMK/index.asp) for example. The key reason for using mechanical latching relays is that they will indefinitely hold position without any power consumption, after the set or reset pulse switches them.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I'll need something smaller and under $10...not sure this solution will work for me

Comment: @PeterBennett Looks like I might have to do that..I just wanted to avoid using an ac adapter because of their size, it's hard to find decent small ones for under $10

Comment: Would something like this work? http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/G6BU-1114P-US-DC24/Z3825-ND/369137

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a latching relay would be an excellent choice:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet/EC2-12TNU/399-11031-5-ND/4291097